# model estimation with feedback loop in variables

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics, multicollinearity, independence, instrumental-variables

I have the following problem regarding fitting of a model where some variables can be biased so that their values are based on knowledge or at good guestimate of $Y$ in the past. In other words: some (not all) $X$ in my model are correlated with $Y$ in a sense that their values were selected based on past values of $Y$.

For a longer read, I can give you an example: let's say I want to open a store in a small city, I know a priori my revenues ($Y$) will not be very high (or I am risk averse), therefore I will not rent much space ($X_1$) and will not put much salespeople ($X_2$). And if I was wrong and business is running better than I initially thought ("thought" = previously estimated $Y$), I will put additional salespeople and rent a place with more space after warm-up period.

On the other hand, if I put more salespeople, they are not there only for handling transactions -- they also drive new sales, therefore they should be (somehow) included in my model, but only to the extent they do not include my prior knowledge on $Y$. Same with floor space - I have more stuff to sell so my shop is more attractive now, and revenues ($Y$) should increase.

One constraint to considerations: I am observing only current values of variables, no history.

I was thinking of estimating model without those variables and estimate floor and salespeople effect by doing a second fit on error terms, but if people and floor are correlated to some extent with other variables, their predictive power will be "overshadowed" by variables I included at the first step.

$$
Y = \beta_{01} + \beta_3 \times X_3 + \epsilon_1
$$ $$
\epsilon_1 = \beta_{02}  + \beta_1 \times X_1 + \beta_2 \times X_2 + \epsilon_2
$$

I have also been considering something related to instrument variables, but I admit I lack theoretical grounds here on when and how to use it.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to regress $X_1$ on $X_3$ (and other variables that I include in top-level model) and select residuals from this additional model as an input to top-level model? By doing this, I eliminate from $X_1$ the variability which is correlated with my expectations on future levels of $Y$ and leaves solely the true effect of $X_1$ I want to measure.